# How do you convert a Data Table Column to a List of string in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, list, datatables

I have a Data Table with one column in it. I want to take that Data Table column and either convert it straight into a list of string.

I have tried using a For Each loop to get each data row item and write it to a list of string but when I'm looking at the output after using a Write Line, I get "System.Data.DataRow" instead of the row value which would be something like "11363".

Here is the data table. The row title is "Codes". The values below the column title are what I want added to a list of string.

```
[Codes
11361
11362
11363
15509
16494
16898
17333
19550
]
```

Here is the code that I have tried to use that is not working for me.

```
ForEach row As DataRow in ExampleDataTable
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.ToString.Trim)
        ExampleList.Add(row.ToString)
    End If
Next

ForEach item As String in ExampleList
    Console.WriteLine(item)
Next
```

The output I get from that after using a For Each loop to print out everything in the list is:

```
System.Data.DataRow
System.Data.DataRow
System.Data.DataRow
System.Data.DataRow
System.Data.DataRow
System.Data.DataRow
System.Data.DataRow
System.Data.DataRow
```

What I want it to output is:

```
11361
11362
11363
15509
16494
16898
17333
19550
```

Can anyone help me out with this? I've read a lot of posts now on Stack Overflow as well as MSDN and I'm just not able to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add the whole row.  Add the column by using row.item(colName or ColNumber)

```
Dim ExampleList As New List(Of String)
For Each row As DataRow In ExampleDataTable.Rows
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Item("Codes")) Then
        ExampleList.Add(row.Item("Codes").ToString)
    End If
Next
```

EDIT: Code above now corrected to compile OK.  A LINQ version would be:

```
Dim ExampleList = (From rw As DataRow In ExampleDataTable.Rows
                   Where Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(rw.Item("Codes"))
                   Select rw.Item("Codes")
                   ).ToList()
```

Comment: Not sure why someone voted this down but this is it! I'm sure there's probably like a Linq way to do this that is more "elegant" and I'd like to know how to do this but I just think it is dumb that they voted you down and didn't provide a solution of their own. Thank you very much for the speedy response!

Comment: Thank you for clarifying Jon. It was clear to me initially but may be more helpful to other users in the future as it is now. Still leaving this as the answer.

Comment: `Code above now corrected to compile`, sure it will compile, *but* `ExampleList` has not been initialized, it will throw an exception when you hit `ExampleList.Add(row.Item("Codes").ToString)` the first time...

Answer (score 3):

Jon was probably down voted because that code wont compile. He forgot some things, such as including the Rows collection for iteration, and when checking the null he is actually checking the row itself, not the value.

```
    Dim StrList As New List(Of String)
    For Each DtRow As DataRow In dt.Rows
        If DtRow("ColumnName") IsNot Nothing Then
            StrList.Add(DtRow("ColumnName").ToString)
        End If
    Next
```

Your question was probably down voted becuase a simple google search produces maybe 10 results how to do this, now 11.

This will probably be down voted because its not a comment, so maybe up vote it because I need 4 pts to start leaving comments.

Comment: As the solution was simple,I copy / pasted the code from the original question and just corrected the one error being referenced, so leaving the original errors present.  I thought that was clear enough for the OP, which it was, but it was a little lazy of me.  A down vote's maybe a little harsh, but lesson learnt!

Comment: Some people are picky around here. I was only assuming that was the reason.

Comment: `Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(DtRow("ColumnName").ToString)`will still throw an exception. The reason is because if `DtRow("ColumnName")` is nothing calling `ToString` will throw the exception...

Comment: Thank you for your response but I disagree with your statement that “a simple google search produces maybe 10 results“. It wasn’t that simple for me. This post is clearer than anything I found on google and will help a lot of people out in the future.

Comment: “Column Name” is a required parameter in my method so this isn’t even applicable in my scenario but may be helpful to others. Time and votes will tell.

Comment: @Mark What are you even talking about? Do you suppose I meant for you to keep the 'ColumnName' placeholder? Also, yes, there are many google results with exactly these solutions, including the Linq

Comment: I mean you can't run the Sub Routine that I created in my programming without providing the "Column Name" parameter, so it's not  even applicable to my code. Also, there may be google results but I guess you're the only one who's able to find them with a "simple search".

Answer (score 1):

`Enumerable.Range(0,dt.ColumnCount).Select(Function(x) dt.Columns(x).ToString).ToList()`

Comment: I had to alter the dt.ColumnCount part for this to work:
``Enumerable.Range(0, dt.Columns.Count).Select(Function(x) dt.Columns(x).ToString).ToList()``
but it got me on the right track and is much nicer than using a For Each loop.